# Cassandra select and insert atomic operation

Tags: python, cassandra, atomic

If two machines execute the below python function with same params(id and domainEnv), I want only first one to insert the column and return true from function. But some cases are happening where both are returning true as both select and insert is not an atomic operation.  Can I get some inputs on how to make them atomic and return true only once.
.....> code

```
maxTTL = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60
cassandraCreateTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.model_deploy (column1 text, column2 text, column3_flag text, modified_date text, primary key(column1));"
cassandraSelectFlag = "SELECT column3_flag FROM test.model_deploy WHERE column1 = ?;"
cassandraInsertQuery = "INSERT INTO test.model_deploy (column1, column2, column_flag, modified_date) values (?, ?, ?, ?) using ttl ?;"

def checkNoColumn1Exists(id, domainEnv):
'''
1. Check if column 1 row with id exists :
a. If not exists -> insert the row and return true
b. If yes -> do nothing and return false
'''
try:
  cassandraCluster = ["....> I have my details entered here"]
  authProvider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username='xxx', password='xxx')
  cluster = Cluster(cassandraCluster, auth_provider=authProvider)
  session = cluster.connect()
  preparedQuery = session.prepare(cassandraSelectFlag)
  insertQuery = session.prepare(cassandraInsertQuery)
  currentTime = str(datetime.datetime.now())
  rows = session.execute(preparedQuery, [id])
  setFlag = 'true'
  if len(rows.current_rows) == 0:
    session.execute(insertQuery, [id, domainEnv, setFlag, currentTime, maxTTL])
    return True
  return False
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is that you have two application running the same functionality and you want only one application to insert the data. I believe the data that both applications are inserting is same including the primary key  and rest of the table columns.

In this case, I would not worry if both application write data. Cassandra is write intensive database. Writes in Cassandra are awfully cheap.

Now the question of which data persist in table. If you recall, every column cell in Cassandra is associated with a timestamp. Whichever application writes later, that data will persist. While compaction, Cassandra use the latest timestamp of the cell and that will be persisted.

We do not have to worry about the atomicity while using Cassandra. In above code you are destroying the atomicity by doing check-then-act.

Now lets say, both the applications are going to insert different data for rest of the column but same primary key. In this case we have to change table definition to add clustering columns.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.model_deploy 
(
 column1 text, 
 column2 text, 
 column3_flag text, 
 modified_date text, 
 primary key((column1), column2, column3_flag, modified_date)
);
```